# Use Regexp to replace optional match between charaters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I'm trying to replace the html entity for a blank space with an actual space between occurrences of {{ and  }}

Example example

```
"this is a &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; gap {{ &nbsp;for user in&nbsp;users&nbsp;}}" =>
"this is a &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; gap {{  for user in users }}"
```

I've found answers similar which had led me to write something like this (which doesn't work)

```
.gsub(/(?<=\{\{).*(&nbsp;?).*(?=\}\})/,' ')
```

Any help with such a regex would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: You only want to replace between the `{{braces}}`, right?

Comment: only replace `&nbsp;` with a space between {{ }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Single call to gsub using `\K` and `\G`**

It's a bit tricky, but in Ruby 2.0+, we can do it with a compact regex thanks to the `\K` and `\G` tokens. Use this regex and replace with a space:

```
[^{}]*\K(?:{{|\G).*?\K&nbsp;(?=[^{]*})
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/hM2tD0).

In Ruby:

```
result = subject.gsub(/[^{}]*\K(?:{{|\G).*?\K&nbsp;(?=[^{]*})/, ' ')
```

**Explanation**

- `[^{}]*` matches any chars that are not braces
- `\K` tells the engine to drop what was just matched
- `(?:{{|\G)` either matches the opening curlies or asserts that we are positioned after the last match
- `.*?\K` lazily matches chars (and drops them), up to...
- `&nbsp;` Our match!
- which, as the lookakead `(?=[^{]*})` asserts, must be followed by any chars that are not an opening brace before meeting a closing brace

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a complex regular expression I agree, but I find it simpler to use **nested** substitution. First use gsub to find the bracketed substrings and then use another to replace the entity.

```
string = 'this is a &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; gap {{ &nbsp;for user in&nbsp;users&nbsp;}}'
result = string.gsub(/{{.*?}}/){ |s| s.gsub(/&nbsp;/, ' ') }
# => "this is a &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; gap {{  for user in users }}"
```

Comment: To clarify it for him, this solution (which works) chains two consecutive replace operations.